# C# Change thread name cmd.exe to xxx.exe

Tags: c#, windows, batch-file, cmd

I've wanted to make an C# Application which creates an batch that closes all cmd's and Taskmanager's in a loop. It works perfectly with "taskmgr.exe" but if I add that it should close all cmd's it closes itself too. Is there a way to change the thread name of itself so it isn't called anymore cmd.exe?

My code:

```cs
File.Delete(path);
using (var tw = new StreamWriter(path, true))
{
    tw.WriteLine(":ttt");
    tw.WriteLine("taskkill /f /Im taskmgr.exe");
    tw.WriteLine("goto ttt:");
    tw.WriteLine("pause");
    tw.Close();
    File.SetAttributes(path, FileAttributes.Hidden);
}
Process.Start(path);
```

Comment: copy C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe and run the copy ?

Comment: i want to make it in c# so how?
edit: it should work on other Pc's well too

Comment: I would think about it differently. Identify your running thread and close all threads that are cmd.exe with a check to make sure it's not yours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is some misunderstanding here, there is no thread name called "cmd.exe", it's just that when you run your application, it creates a batch file, and then the `Process.Start(path);` runs a new cmd application to run this newly created batch script inside of it (since by definition, .bat scripts are cmd programs).

I would rather directly kill the task managers and the cmds from within your program using something like:

```
while(true){
    foreach (Process proc in Process.GetProcessesByName("cmd"))
    {
        proc.Kill();
    }
    foreach (Process proc in Process.GetProcessesByName("taskmgr"))
    {
        proc.Kill();
    }
    // Sleep for 2 seconds, so that the program does not do this too often.
    Thread.Sleep(2000);
}
```

Comment: op is using a console application, not windows forms and console app is a cmd.exe itself

Comment: Op can use this answer und skip the parent pid. It is really not very elegant to spawn a Cmd script if the system access functions readily exists

Comment: @Joe_DM I don't think so. I think what is killed is the bat which is run by the `Process.Start(path);`. The executable of his program is certainly not named `cmd.exe`, and there is no indication that op is running his program in a cmd, he could as well be running it directly from visual, using powershell or even double-clicking it, which should not especially run a new cmd.

Comment: @Thundzz I think you're right, I misunderstood the op question. Console app would not be called cmd.exe unless it was executed from within a cmd console to begin with, either way I think the op has enough to work this out from here on.

Comment: but how can i make a loop for it :P im very bad at coding and if im doing a while loop it freezes the application

Comment: Why catch the error at all, the loop will still be broken and error handling is outside the scope of this question.

Comment: @Joe_DM right, I removed the error handling. Just reflexes speaking.

Comment: @Mad_Luffy The program is already looping through every single cmd and task manager, I don't understand what other loop you could be talking about.

Comment: @Thundzz If i Open an cmd / taskmanager afterwards it wont close

EDIT: NMV fixed it with an backgroundworker thanks

Comment: I added the loop, even if it was outside the scope of the original question. If you could edit the question to include the looping, it would be cool.

Comment: lol. I love the while true... may the user never bash again. :)

Comment: @Joe_DM Op got what he asked for :D